# what does 게 mean in this sentence - 네가 내 친구란 행운이야?

Tags: meaning, usage

네가 내 친구란 **게** 행운이야.

I'm happy that you are my friend.

I think 란 works as `that`.

What is this "게"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a pro at Korean grammar so bear with me while I try explain this.

I think you mean 네가 내 친구**란게** 행운이야. I'm not sure where you got this sentence from, but I'm assuming it was said by someone. In written form it should be, 네가 내 친구**라는 겄이** 행운이야 or 네가 내 친구**라는게** 행운이야.

게 in this case works with -란 from the previous word to make -란게 and that translates to 'the fact that'. We can try break the sentence down word for word for a better understanding:

`네가:` You are

`내 친구:` My friend

`란게:` The fact that

`행운이야:` It's luck/fortune

So if we're talking word for word, '네가 내 친구**란게** 행운이야' directly translates to:

> You are my friend, **that fact** is luck/a fortune.

But that sounds strange in the english language, so if i simplify it, it becomes:

> **The fact that** you're my friend is luck/a fortune.

But the sentence sounds awkward so it just becomes:

> I'm lucky to have you as my friend.

Another example using the -란게 could be:

내가 여자**라는게** 좋아: I like **the fact that** I'm a girl <- Where in this case I expanded 란 to 라는.

As mentioned briefly above, Koreans tend to shorten words when pronouncing them, so 라는게 becomes 란게. I hope that helped!

Comment: The sentence is cited from a book native Korean writes.

Comment: "-란" is short for "-라는." "게" is short for "것이." And you space before the noun "것." "-란 게," "-라는 게," "-란 것이," "-라는 것이."

Comment: You wrote "네가 내 친구라는 겄이", it is 것이, isn't it?